# invoke back button press from code behind in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to invoke a back button press from code?

I want to simulate a physical back button press from the code behind for a page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[NavigationService.GoBack()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.goback%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) will do just that.

Answer (score 5):

You can't simulate a physical back button press. What I mean is you won't be able to navigate back from the first page, i.e. exit the application. Currently the only way for a WP7 Silverlight application to exit is to throw an exception. That said, if you just want to navigate back to another page in your app [NavigationService.GoBack()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.goback%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) will do the trick as keyboardP said.

By the way, why do you need to simulate a back button press? If you want to exit the app here's a [nice article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/01/exiting-a-windows-phone-application.aspx) by Peter Torr explaining the various ways a WP7 app can exit. He also analyses scenarios that need exit functionality and talks about what can be done instead. In general, if you have some page with an ok/cancel buttons and you want the cancel to go back or exit, you can just remove it and let the user press the back button.

Comment: Technically, if you use `GoBack` on the first page, an exception is thrown so your app will close anyway :D

Comment: @keyboardP Nice, I haven't looked at it this way :) I wouldn't use this in my code though, since it works only by coincidence and would probably be confusing to other developers.

Comment: Absolutely, it's not good to rely on that as a real program flow. Would be nice to have a real exit method, although I guess the idea is to design the app in such a way that the back button works perfectly.

Comment: @keyboardP Yeah, I think that's the idea. I'm not sure how well that works in practice - I haven't come across many situations where you really need exit, but I don't have nearly enough experience to say there aren't such situations. I added a link to an article that discusses some common "exit" scenarios and how to address them.